# в Unity 3d гг постоянно застревает в любых горках

Tags: unity3d

В Unity стоит вид от третьего лица, скрипт использую обычный из SampleScenes
Скрипт:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class ThirdPersonUserControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ThirdPersonCharacter m_Character; // A reference to the ThirdPersonCharacter on the object
        private Transform m_Cam;                  // A reference to the main camera in the scenes transform
        private Vector3 m_CamForward;             // The current forward direction of the camera
        private Vector3 m_Move;
        private bool m_Jump;                      // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.

        
        private void Start()
        {
            // get the transform of the main camera
            if (Camera.main != null)
            {
                m_Cam = Camera.main.transform;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(
                    "Warning: no main camera found. Third person character needs a Camera tagged \"MainCamera\", for camera-relative controls.", gameObject);
                // we use self-relative controls in this case, which probably isn't what the user wants, but hey, we warned them!
            }

            // get the third person character ( this should never be null due to require component )
            m_Character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }
        }


        // Fixed update is called in sync with physics
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // read inputs
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

            // calculate move direction to pass to character
            if (m_Cam != null)
            {
                // calculate camera relative direction to move:
                m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
                m_Move = v*m_CamForward + h*m_Cam.right;
            }
            else
            {
                // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
                m_Move = v*Vector3.forward + h*Vector3.right;
            }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // walk speed multiplier
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) m_Move *= 0.5f;
#endif

            // pass all parameters to the character control script
            m_Character.Move(m_Move, crouch, m_Jump);
            m_Jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет ну, судя по твоим словам, у тебя проблема  в методе `Написать нормальный вопрос()` класса `Вопрос` . Попробуй добавить в него описание, либо же код и тогда ошибка исчезнет.

Comment: ну наверное, но какой смысл добавлять код если написал что использую user control из samplescenes. Я вообще недавно начал разбираться поэтому наверное выглядит глупо. Если не сложно напишите что добавить в вопрос, я добавлю

Comment: Смысл в том, что никто не знает что такое 'user control' стандартной пустой сцены `SampleScene`. Никто не может понять что у вас написано в реализации вида от третьего лица. Это совершенно ни о чем не говорит, как если бы я сказал "у меня игра 2д не работает отображение текста на сцене Game". Поэтому добавьте скрипт движения, поворота камеры, опишите проблему поглубже чем то что у вас написано сейчас

Comment: Попробую, спасибо